# Is it possible to use Angular components without Angular modules?

Tags: angular

I love the component templating engine Angular uses but don't need DI or the router.

Is it possible to just use the components/templating engine?

Answer (score 2):

Angular need a module to create the component thru module component factory. And a lot of things is made controlling these modules, like lazy loading. So no. Only if you declare your components in one main module.

Answer (score 1):

Angular v15 comes with this feature. You don't have to use modules anymore since components can do the module-related stuff. https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's not Possible Because even a single Component Should be in app.module.ts
Which is a module i.e.., main module,
if u multiple components and  You don't want a separate module then u can just Import it in app.module.ts

for more clear knowledge  go through this :https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f